# Como retirar os títulos(em tempo de execução) e diminuir o tamanho de FloatingActionButton?

Tags: android

Tenho um menu, com floating action buttons e gostaria de saber como é possível colocá-los menor que o tamanho normal, pois eles são iguais, em tamanho, ao menu, mesmo aberto e a propriedade fabsize não funciona. E como retirar o titulo programaticamente ao ser clicado um botão destes qualquer?

XML:

```
<com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu
                android:id="@+id/map_btn_compartilhar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/pink_icon"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/multiple_actions_down"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/multiple_actions_down"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_share_white_24dp"
                app:fab_addButtonStrokeVisible="true"
                fab:fab_addButtonColorNormal="@color/fundo_3"
                fab:fab_addButtonColorPressed="@color/fundo_1"
                fab:fab_labelStyle="@style/menu_labels_style">

                <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                    android:id="@+id/fab_ativa_map"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_map_24dp_branco_deactive"
                    fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/white"
                    fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/white_pressed"
                    fab:fab_title="@string/ativarmap_map"/>

                <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                    android:id="@+id/fab_filtra_map"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_24dp_branco_deactive"
                    fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/white"
                    fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/fundo_2"
                    fab:fab_title="@string/filtra_map"/>

                <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                    android:id="@+id/fab_parar_map"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_24dp_branco_active"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/fundo_1"
                    fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/fundo_2"
                    fab:fab_title="@string/pararmap_map" />

</com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu>
```

Exemplo do código do FAB:

```
fabAtivamap = (com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton) activity.findViewById(R.id.fab_ativa_map);
        fabAtivamap.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);       
        fabAtivamap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {                            
                ......
                // Reseta os botões
                fabPararmap.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                fabAtivamap.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                fabFiltramap.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                fabAtivamap.setTitle("");//retirar os titulos
                ......
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Tem alguma razão especial para usar uma `library` que o próprio autor diz que é [extremamente limitada](https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button#caveats)?

Não sei se vai funcionar com esta `library`, mas usando `FAB` da biblioteca do material design, você controla o tamanho assim:

```
app:fabSize="mini"
```

Para o tamanho minimo (padrão 40x40 dp)

```
app:fabSize="normal"
```

Para o tamanho normal (padrão 56x56 dp)

Tente e veja se funciona, ou deixe de usar esta [biblioteca](https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button), que ai, vai funcionar.

Comment: usei pq na epoca foi o que achei. Como disse, não funciona, dessa forma que me mostrou.